# Cannot enable GPS  on G510

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gps

I have an Android G510 running 2.3.4 but cannot access the GPS. In "Location & Security" there is no GPS item, just "Use wireless networks".

Can anyone help please

Is there any test I can do to check?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a site](http://www.vkamobi.com/gps-cell-phone/g510-google-android-gps-tv-touch-screen-smartphone.html) that has the specs for the G510, and it does say that it supports GPS. Maybe there is a problem with the hardware on the device that the GPS chip doesn't work or something, and the software doesn't see the chip so it doesn't show the option.

You can try using the "Power Control" widget if you have it (i think its part of stock android). It has a toggle for GPS, and you can see if it lets you turn it on/off.